# Problema com loop while no PDO

Tags: php, mysql

Boas pessoal estou aqui com um problema no `PDO` quero fazer um while mas fiz a `query` e no fim só me e retornado um valor desse `while` não sei o que possa estar a ocorrer

**Código**

```
$result = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM colecoes WHERE menu = :menu AND activo = :activo ORDER BY pos ASC ");
$result->execute(array(':menu' => 'Comer', 'activo' => '1'));
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
```

Exemplo

```
 <?php

$result = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM colecoes WHERE menu = :menu AND activo = :activo ORDER BY pos ASC");
$result->bindValue(':menu', 'Comer', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':activo', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
while($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 

$result_anex = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM colecoes_anexos WHERE id_mae = :row_id AND seccao = :seccao");
$result_anex->bindValue(':row_id', $row->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result_anex->bindValue(':seccao', 'thumbnail', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result_anex->execute();
$row_anex = $result_anex->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$result_count = $conexao->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM categorias_estabelecimentos WHERE categoria_slug = :categoria_slug ") or
die(mysql_error());
$result_count->execute(array(':categoria_slug' => $row->slug));
$bar = $result_count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
  <!--item-->
  <div class="entry one-fourth wow fadeInLeft">
    <figure>
        <a href="estabelecimentos/<?php echo $row->slug; ?>" style="cursor:pointer;"><img style="border-radius:10px;" src="gtm/anexos/colecoes/<?php echo $row_anex->id_anexo; ?>.<?php echo $row_anex->tipo ?>" alt="<?php echo utf8_encode($row_anex->titulo); ?>&h=203&w=270&a=c" /></a>
        <a href="estabelecimentos/<?php echo $row->slug; ?>"><div style="position:absolute; margin-left:0px; color:white; font-weight: bold; background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5); padding:2px 5px 0px 20px; margin-top:-140px;"><?php echo $bar['id']; ?> ESTABELECIMENTOS</div></a>
        <a href="estabelecimentos/<?php echo $row->slug; ?>"><div style="position:absolute; margin-left:0px; color:white; font-weight: bold; background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5); padding:2px 5px 0px 20px; margin-top:-100px;"><?php echo utf8_encode($row->titulo); ?></div></a>
        <!--<figcaption><a href="recipe.html"><i class="ico i-view"></i> <span>View recipe</span></a></figcaption>-->
    </figure>
   </div>
   <!--item-->
   <?php
  }
   ?>
```

Comment: Esqueceu os dois pontos (:) no array de parâmetros :activo ali, e você pode usar o fetchAll para retornar todos os dados.

Comment: Se executar a consulta diretamente pelo banco ele retornar mais de uma linha? `fetch` retorna apenas uma linha, `fetchAll` todas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esqueceu de adicionar os **dois pontos no array de parâmetros**, no caso o parâmetro `activo (:activo)` e para retornar mais que um dado, utilize o fetchAll.

Segue o código final:

```
try
{    
    $result = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM colecoes WHERE menu = :menu AND activo = :activo ORDER BY pos ASC");
    $result->bindValue(':menu', 'Comer', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindValue(':activo', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        //Continuação
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54284/discussion-on-answer-by-rafael-withoeft-problema-com-loop-while-no-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

`while(false != ($row = $fetch->fetchAll(arg))){}`

Experimenta isto e para o caso de duvidas recomendo que visite o site php.net